# Deploying new WCF Services in the same box

Tags: .net, wcf, iis

I have written 3 new WCF 4.0 Services which at the moment are hosted on my VS2010 IIS.
I would like to deploy them in a standalone IIS 6.0 box. The services listen to different port numbers lets say 1601,1602,1603. 
Do I need to create 3 new WebSites on IIS and in each one of them deploy the files, and setup the different port number?

Rgds,
MK

Comment: You don't need a new TCP Port for each new Web Service - you can create as many SVC's as you like on Port 80? But yes, AFAIK if you need to listen on different ports you would need a separate site for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to do that. You COULD probably have one site listening to all those ports and then in the service deny calls from some port numbers, but it's much easier to just have 3. That's how it's normally done.

Question is, why do you want them to listen to different ports? You could separate them by virtual directories?

Comment: So you are saying have 1 website listening to 1 port (i.e. 1601) with 3 vistual directories and each one contains the code for each service?

Comment: That's how it's been done in all projects where I've worked with web services. I think thats pretty much standard.